# mysql select user defined value for not existing column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo

I want to be able to add a not existing column name and column value into my select. I am using php pdo code igniter.

sample code is :

```
$this->db->select('* ,code1 AS  `column` ');
```

When I try in phpmyadmin like :

```
SELECT *,'code1' AS `column` from table
```

It is working but in code it is not. When I look at dev tools I see

> Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'code1' in 'field list'SELECT *, `code1` 
>   AS `column` FROM

Getting `#1054 - Unknown column '' in 'field list'`

I tried adding `@` into the column value

How to add a column name column value in mysql select that the user will define

Comment: question has no flaws. still down-voted.+1 from my side as i don't think any problem is there in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pass false as a second parameter in [`select()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

```
$this->db->select("* ,'code1' AS  `column` ",FALSE);
```

your current generated query is like

```
select * from `code1` as `column`
```

See backtics added around code1 which does not exist in your table, if its just a string value then put quotes around it 'code1'

> As per docs $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names. This is useful if you need a compound select statement where automatic escaping of fields may break them.

Comment: if i do `$this->db->select("* ,{$code} AS  `column` ",FALSE);`  where `$code` is a variable which is what I really wanted I still get error when static it works

Comment: @guradio see my updated answer you need to put that value in quotes so that mysql will treat it as string not column, For your case this should work `$this->db->select("* ,' ".$code." ' AS somecolumn ",FALSE);`

Comment: great to learn new things also `column` i think is reserve i cant memorize them all :) can you add about the `column` in answer as well

Comment: @guradio ye its a reserved word use another name for your custom column